# Why do I get the error "Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h" when I try to install rmagick?

Tags: rubygems, imagemagick, solaris, rmagick

I recently started migrating my sites from Accelerator to SmartMachine.

Everything was okay, but now I can't install the rmagick gem. When I run `sudo gem install rmagick`, the console shows the message:

> Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.

MagickWand.h is in `/opt/local/includes/ImageMagick/wand`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try: apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

Or: C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/ImageMagick/ gem install rmagick

Or: $ MAGICK_HOME=/usr/local bundle